# How to remove an index from the output has been generated in R?

Tags: r

At first I was importing data set in the form of csv by eliminating the column name and the name of the line.
The command as below.

```
library(readr)
katatidakbaku <- read_csv("D:/Materi Kuliah/R/katatidakbaku.csv", col_names = FALSE,row.names(NULL))
```

After I though that data with the code below:

```
kataSlank<-function(input){
  list2<-list(katatidakbaku[1])
  kamus_kataSlank1<-unlist(list2)

  list3<-list(katatidakbaku[2])
   kamus_kataSlank2<-unlist(list3)

  n <- 5000
  for(i in 1:n){
  if (input %in% kamus_kataSlank1[i])
    kata1<-return(kamus_kataSlank2[i])

  }
}
```

katatidakbaku is the name of the data set I have imported, consisting of two columns.

After running the above program will perform its output as below

```
kataSlank("abis")
```

output

```
X21   
"habis"
```

abis is a random input. I want to delete `X21`. I just need the output only that is "habis".
`habis` is one of the content of the data set that have been processed by the program based on the input `abis` .

`X21` describes the second column and the first line. If given the other input then index will also change.

example

```
kataSlank("nmun")
```

output

```
X22623   
"namun"
```

I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: maybe `unname(kataSlank("abis"))` is what you need.

Comment: this is very helpful @RonakShah .Thank you.

Comment: guess its now solved?

Comment: yes. it's been solved @datBoy thank you